# PHP - print the result of a boolean expression

Tags: php

I expect the following code to print "false"

```
<?php
    $a = 4;
    $b = 45;
    echo $a==$b;
?>
```

but prints nothing.

Comment: `echo ($a==$b) ? 'true' : 'false';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't print anything because the result of `$a==$b` is a boolean, and `false` is converted to an empty string. Use `var_dump` instead (if you are debugging your code):

```
var_dump($a==$b);
```

Or alternatively you can use `echo` this way:

```
echo ($a==$b) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

`false` is rendered as an empty string(`''`) in PHP, `true` as `'1'`.

These days `json_decode()` is an easy, reliable option to get `'true'`/`'false'` if you're sure your variable or expression result is a boolean:

```php
echo json_decode($a == $b);
```

Another option is `var_export()` which, despite the name, seems to accept an expression nowadays:

```php
var_export($a == $b); // option one, directly print
echo var_export($a == $b, true); // option 2, get string and print it yourself
```